# Cannot find gapi functions with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, google-api-js-client

I wanted to use the Google's JS API, so I included it into my index.html and installed the typings with `typings install dt~gapi --global --save`

My IDE (Webstorm), shows me that the variable gapi has `auth` and `client` as function, but it shows me no sub-functions of these two. When I include
`/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/gapi/index.d.ts" />` at the top of my Service everything works.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/gapi/index.d.ts" />
export class foo {
  constructor() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      //my config  
    });
  }
}
```

So did I miss anything or is this the right way?

Comment: I'm having (I think) the same problem. Can you add some code?

Comment: Added some code

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue recently, here are some configurations that worked for me:

I'm using DefinitelyTyped [@types/gapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi) package.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/gapi
```

From typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), use `/// <reference types="..." />` directive to load types in your typescript file:

```
/// <reference types="gapi" />
```

Additional configurations I have in `tsconfig.json` file at the root of my project:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // I thought this was enough to recognize the types
    // but that was not the case
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    ...
  }
}
```

Make sure you use typescript v2.0 or later.